# python - Create a column combining the first and last name columns with IF Statement

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a Full Name column that will join strings from the First_Name column and the Last_Name column which works fine with the below code

```
cols = ['First_Name', 'Last_Name']
df['Full_Name'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

What I'd like to do now is insert an **IF statement**;
If the First_Name column is blank or the Last_Name column is blank then return the value unique_Identifier column.
Else join the strings from the First_Name and Last_Name column.

**Desired Outcome**

| unique_Identifier | First_Name | Last_Name | Full_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | Michael | O Brien | Michael O Brien |
| 22222 |  |  | 22222 |
| 33333 | Josh |  | 33333 |
| 44444 | Rebecca | Mullins | Rebecca Mullins |
| 55555 | Pat | Horgan | Pat Horgan |
| 66666 | Mary | Sisk | Mary Sisk |
| 77777 |  | Buckley | 77777 |
| 88888 | Mary | Poppins | Mary Poppins |
| 99999 | Michelle | O Shea | Michelle O Shea |

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample dataframe:

```
   Unique_Identifier First_Name   Last_Name
0                108     Morgen  Chansonnau
1                109    Richard     Martins
2                110                Kemwall
3                111       Bari        Carr
4                112   Grantley     Laurenz
5                113                 Headey
6                114     Nathan      Govier
7                115  Konstance
8                116        Dru       Colin
9                117      Karel  D'Ambrosio
```

Use `np.where`:

```
df['Full_Name'] = np.where(df[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']].eq('').any(axis=1),
                           df['Unique_Identifier'],
                           df[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']].apply(' '.join, axis=1))
```

```
>>> df
   Unique_Identifier First_Name   Last_Name          Full_Name
0                108     Morgen  Chansonnau  Morgen Chansonnau
1                109    Richard     Martins    Richard Martins
2                110                Kemwall                110
3                111       Bari        Carr          Bari Carr
4                112   Grantley     Laurenz   Grantley Laurenz
5                113                 Headey                113
6                114     Nathan      Govier      Nathan Govier
7                115  Konstance                            115
8                116        Dru       Colin          Dru Colin
9                117      Karel  D'Ambrosio   Karel D'Ambrosio
```